# System account stops workflow process

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, error, email

I'm encountering with workflow in SharePoint 2010. I realize that System account stopped workflow process whenever. The workflow history has the following:

- Event Type: Error
- User ID: System Account
- Description: The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail
  has valid recipient

I haven't known reason yet. I would live to know why I saw the above errors.

Notice: I configured properly Outgoing email as well as valid recipient email. I'm using Exchange Server 2007 and configured Connector.

Regards.

Comment: How are you populating the recipient in the email step of the workflow?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Clearly a config problem as we cannot replicate the issue in any other environment. We are using claims and ADFS for authentication although we have a claim NTLM site provisioned as an extended web app. I can't send emails from our relay server or from the local smtp. I can send emails from both without issue from telnet. There is NOTHING in the logs indicating there is an issue. I have set verbose logging for foundation, server and portal server. I have also put a snippet in the webconfig that enabled more robust logging from workflow and there are no errors

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Smart Relay host on a seperate server or a local SMTP server for outgoing email? Does it use authenticated relay? Is the AppPool account for the sites parent web application granted relay permissions? Are you assigning a domain user account that may not have a valid email address configured, assuming that all domain users have valid email addresses?

You have a configuration problem - keep digging.

Comment: I think that my error concerns Application Pool or some services, which are conflict with my workflow process.